# How to create error messages validate form input with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have the register form as below:

```
<div class="form">
    <form class="register-form" name="register-form">
        <ul class="errorMessages"></ul>
         <div class="user-name">
             <input class="wrap" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="firstname" required/>
              <input class="wrap" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="lastname" required/>
              </div>
          <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off" required/>
          <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="email address" autocomplete="off" required/>
          button class="btn-signup" type="submit">Create</button>
          <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
</div>
```

I create JQuery code check if input is blank, this will create error message"

```
$(function() {
    var createAllErrors = function () {
        var form = $(".register-form");
        var errorList = $('ul.errorMessages', form);

        var showAllErrorMessages = function () {
            errorList.empty();

            form.find(':invalid').each(function (index, node) {
                var label = $('input').attr('name');
                var message = node.validationMessage || 'Invalid value.';
                errorList
                    .show()
                    .append('<li><span>' + label + ': ' + '</span>' + message + '</li>');
            });
        };
        $('input[type=submit], button', form).on('click', showAllErrorMessages);
    };
    $('form').each(createAllErrors);
});
```

But when I press button I have result:

[image]

Any problem about label variable? or on form find invalid input?

Comment: Check if following solves your issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is inside your each loop. You're never using the current index, and instead you requery the whole dom in search for `input` elements. Whenn you call getter functions on a jQuery collection, jQuery will return the attribute of the first element inside the collection. In your case this is the `firstname` input element.  Use the current element of the each loop instead:

```
form.find(':invalid').each(function (index, node) {

  // WRONG: This will always return firstname
  //var label = $('input').attr('name');

  // RIGHT: Access the current element inside each loop
  var label = $(node).attr('name');

  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find "each" input which is "invalid". Following line is problematic in your current code.

```
//this will always find first 'input' element in the DOM!
  var label = $('input').attr('name');
```

Following should fix your issue,

```
    $(function() {
    var createAllErrors = function () {
       var form = $(".register-form");
       var errorList = $('ul.errorMessages', form);

       var showAllErrorMessages = function () {
       errorList.empty();

       form.find(':invalid').each(function () {
            // for each invalid input find it's attribute 'name'
            var label = $(this).attr('name');
            var message = $(this).validationMessage || 'Invalid value.';
            errorList
                .show()
                .append('<li><span>' + label + ': ' + '</span>' + message + '</li>');
            });
       };
       $('input[type=submit], button', form).on('click', showAllErrorMessages);
    };
    $('form').each(createAllErrors);
});
```